# Pandas: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

The following is my code (only mock up numbers):

```
import pandas as pd 
d = {'x' : [1,4,6,9],
     'y' : [1,4,6,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
ct = pd.concat([df.x,
                pd.cut(df.y, bins=2)], axis=1)
gp = ct.groupby('x').y.value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
print(gp)
print(gp[gp.columns[0]])
gp[gp.columns[0]] = gp[gp.columns[0]]/10
```

`print(gp)` gives:

```
y  (0.993, 4.5]  (4.5, 8.0]
x                          
1           1.0         0.0
4           1.0         0.0
6           0.0         1.0
9           0.0         1.0
```

`print(gp[gp.columns[0]])` gives this:

```
x
1    1.0
4    1.0
6    0.0
9    0.0
Name: (0.993, 4.5], dtype: float64
```

But the following line:

```
gp[gp.columns[0]] = gp[gp.columns[0]]/10
```

Throws this error:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: That was strange. I am using Anaconda 64bit. Could that have anything with this to do?

Comment: I use Pandas '0.18.1', 64-bit.

Comment: I am using 0.20.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a bug to me.  Even the following produces an error

```
gp.loc[:, gp.columns[0]] /= 10
```

> ```
> ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)
> ```

However, if you provide labels to the `pd.cut` you solve the problem.

```
d = {'x' : [1,4,6,9],
     'y' : [1,4,6,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
ct = pd.concat([df.x,
                pd.cut(df.y, bins=2, labels=range(2))], axis=1)
gp = ct.groupby('x').y.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

gp.loc[:, gp.columns[0]] /= 10

gp

y    0  1
x        
1  0.1  0
4  0.1  0
6  0.0  1
9  0.0  1
```

Comment: Yes, now it works. I was really start questions my own understanding of Pandas.